# xView Dataset 400 training images are missing?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, satellite-image

I am currently working with the xView Dataset (http://xviewdataset.org/) for my active machine learning master thesis project.
The datatset's homepage claim there are 8457 training images and labels but when i download and extract the big (about 15gb) dataset (splitted into multiple zip files) i only get 376 images. Any clues where and how to retrieve the missing 400 images?

Comment: Are you sure that there were no errors while unzipping?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

xView provides two compression versions for their dataset: .zip and .tgz.
While the .zip was way faster at extracting I ran into the problem of not receiving all images (without any error).
The .tgz extraction took way longer but i ended up with receiving all images.